# Downloading custom audio in musical toys DIY

Tags: diy, music

I am a computer science student and recently interest built into electronics . I want to ask how can i download custom audio in musical toys like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RuA5ifCNSy8) . All i have is this kind of phone toy, Please tell what else i need to purchase to do this DIY.

Comment: Youtube links are always unclear about engineering information; show me the datasheet. Reverse-engineering from a product teardown is often more costly than designing what you actually want. You might find this question relevant: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/150202/simple-audio-sampler-and-looper -- As a computer science student, start with a microcontroller development board, and add a codec and audio amp (LM386 or better). See also Arduino stackexchange Audio questions: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio?sort=votes&pageSize=15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly to your youtube solution, but hope this helps: When in university I've made such a "toy-music" with AtTiny13 MCU. It is a small 8-pin chip.

You simply need to write the music byte by byte in the form like "note", "duration", "note", "duration" and then provide basic code which fetches bytes one after one and turns on the required tone (with an onboard timer) for specified duration. This appeared to be "as easy as lying" even though I have close to zero experience with MCUs at that time.

To upload new music you simply compile your code again with different array of bytes and write it again to the chip.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It was helpful . I will post update in thread with progress .